# Prompt for Facebook permission only if you do not already have basic permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have Facebook Authentication setup on my application using the Facebook Javascript SDK. I currently don't ask for the email permission.  I want to prompt users for email permission but only for users who have not given basic permissions to my site already.

Is there a way to prompt email permission only if they have not given basic permissions to my application?

If possible, I'd like to be able to do this without multiple permissions popups.

Answer (score 1):

Just to see if I understand correctly, you mean that for the users who don't currently have your application authorized, you want to ask for their e-mail permission when you ask them to login, and for users who have you authorized, no change, right?

If so, something like this will do the trick, insert it after your FB.init or on button click or wherever you're doing your FB login right now:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // log the user into your site using FB.getAccessToken() or do whatever you normally do.
    } 
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // ask the user for permissions
        FB.login(function(response) {
            // handle response
        }, {scope: 'email'});
    }
});
```

Caveat: This will do nothing if the user is not currently logged into Facebook and has your application authorized, to make it so it doesn't do this you'll have to replace the else if with just a general else, but it'll show a "Requesting e-mail permission" pop-up to old users when they log in.

Comment: Kasra, thanks for the response.  That caveat is kinda kills what I'm trying to do.  If there was a way to log someone into facbook without asking for any permissions and then checking status this would work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't call `FB.login` from within the `FB.getLoginStatus` callback because browsers will block the resulting popup. That has been my experience.

Comment: @Jakobud browsers are blocking it because it's not coming from a direct user action, are you perhaps calling it on page load rather than on a click of a button?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi that is exactly my point. Since `FB.login` is not being called directly from user input, the browser blocks it. That's why I was pointing out why your method above will not work properly, because you have `FB.login` being called in the `FB.getLoginStatus` callback.